# Every DFA accepting a finite language must contain a dead state?

Tags: finite-automata

I came a across a question where there were some statements made on Finite Automata, DFA and their states.

One such statements in the question was that a "Every DFA accepting a finite language must contain a dead state"

And the answer stated the statement to be true, and showed some DFA where there was a dead state following the accepting/final state.

Yes, dead states after the final state is possible but what about languages like $(a+b)^*$ ? It is a finite language and there is no need for a dead state in it's DFA:

[image: (a+b)* DFA]

There is no dead state in this DFA. Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are making a mistake. There is an important condition here, which is **finite**.

The language $(a+b)^*$ is not finite. For $L$ any language, $L^*$ is finite if and only if $L = \emptyset$ or $L = \{\varepsilon\}$.

Comment: Oh, yeah thanks for pointing it out. That's a silly misconception on my part

Answer (score 0):

> "Every DFA accepting a
> finite language must contain a dead state"

This depends on the definition. If dead state is the same as what some call a garbage state (not accepting, for all letters a loop back to the state) then this statement is *not* true. See the automaton below, which accepts only the empty string. This example can be generalized to other finite languages.

[image: automaton accepting only the empty string without dead state]

Alternatively, dead state might mean at state from which no accepting state is reachable. In that case the above statement is true.